# Accent insensitive searches in Ektron

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ektron, indexing-service

We are running into issues when doing searches with Accent Mark using Ektron CMS. Searching on "Guantánamo" (with accent mark) is returning results but "Guantanamo" is not returning results. Any idea how to get the searches behave insensitive to accent characters?
We suspect we had this functionality working a year back but seems to be broken. Could this be related to any of the windows updates to the Indexing Server?

We are using Windows Server 2008. The Property "Allow Use of diacritics" is Disabled in the 
Local Computer Policy "Computer Configuration/Adminstrative Templates/Windows Components/Search"
Thanks,
Madhu.

Comment: What version of ektron are you using? Older versions (8.0 and before) use Microsoft Index Server for crawling and querying. Newer installations (8.5 and up) support a search provider model, with providers for Search Server, FAST Enterprise Search, etc.

Comment: We are using Ektron 8.01 (this is using Microsoft Index Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just some specific words you could define a synonym so that  Guantánamo is a synonym to Guantanamo.

Comment: I added "Guantánamo" as a synonym in CMS. It works when searching from CMS but does not work from the Application. Do we need to do anything different in the application for the synonym to reflect?

Comment: <cms:WebSearch ID="WebSearch1" runat="server" SearchSynonyms="true"

Comment: Hi, I have made the above change but still it is not working. When I access the CMS Workarea locally  localhost/un/cmslogin.aspx, the Synonym Searches are working. When I try to do the same from the application, they are not. I also added the "SearchSynonyms = true" property to the SearchRequestData object before invoking the Ektron Search API. I restarted the Indexing Service, re-indexed using SearchConfigUI but didnt help. Any idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

From control panel on your search server, open the Indexing Options > Advanced section, and make sure that the "treat similar words with diacritics as different words" option is not selected.

from:
http://programming4.us/desktop/2346.aspx

Comment: We are using Windows Server 2008. I am not able to find the Indexing Options in Control Panel.